# Does organizing code in multiple modules that require the same package decrease performance in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm working with Node.js and Puppeteer, I'm using Puppeteer to scrape multiple websites. I'm thinking of organizing the code by separating each site implementation to its own file. So I will have like example.com.js example2.com.js etc

each of this will will require the same module(puppeteer/jsdom) and will export an object that contains variables and functions. This way, I can import all of these modules in the index.js file.

I've read about Nodejs caching modules and that this way of organizing of code is standard, however, in my case, if say I have 100 different website that I want to scrape, so I will have 100 module that will require (puppeteer/jsdom) in each one of them, so if Nodejs is caching the modules, I'm still using 100 different variables to store the modules.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

So I'll have this line of code in 100 files, even if Nodejs is caching Puppeteer module, I'm still creating 100 puppeteer variable where I could have created just one if I wrote all code in a single file.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

From the official document [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

You're correct about "Nodejs is caching Puppeteer module", but "I'm still creating 100 puppeteer variable" isn't true. So, I would say, don't worry :), you can continue to organize your code in multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if this is your setup:

```js
// a.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// b.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

// c.js
const a = require('./a.js');
const b = require('./b.js');
```

The following will happen;

1. File `a.js` is required
2. The module `puppeteer` is being parsed and referenced by the variable `puppeteer` inside the file.
3. File `b.js` is required
4. Also creates a reference to `puppeteer`, but the module has already been parsed and executed, so it is 'cached'

Doing this won't cause a performance issue, regarding the import of the same module multiple times.

Regarding your statement

> I'm still creating 100 puppeteer variable

As mentioned above, you're only creating references, the contents won't be deeply cloned.

Comment: I have two question. First, will this be the same if I declare puppeteer with let instead of const? Secondly, what if if I change a value inside puppeteer object inside a.js, would b.js access a different new puppeteer object or would b.js access the changed puppeteer object

Comment: 1. Changing from `const` to `let` wouldn't change anything, the only difference is, that the variable referencing puppeteer could be completely overridden.
2. If you change a value inside the `puppeteer` `object`, it will be changed everywhere else, where `puppeteer` is also used (and no deep clone was created beforehand).